# Recursive queue method1(-1)

Tags: java, recursion, methods

I am going through exam questions and have come across this question. I do not understand what the question means.

Question: What would be the result of method1(-1) when D is empty?

I know that when D is empty(or = 0) the method has reached the base case and the recursive method ends. I'm not sure what it means by method(-1).

If anyone could explain this for me, it would be greatly appreciate. Thanks!

```
public void method1(int n){
 if (n == 0) return;
 else{
 String str = (String) D.dequeue();
 D.enqueue(str);
 D.enqueue(str);
 method1(n-1);
 }
}

public void method2(){
 method1(D.size())
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the method just run the step case because there is no other step case or base case to check for anything less than 0?

Comment: The question is asking what would happen if your method input was an int with value `-1`

I̶'̶m̶ ̶g̶u̶e̶s̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶a̶n̶ ̶i̶n̶f̶i̶n̶i̶t̶e̶ ̶l̶o̶o̶p̶,̶ ̶s̶i̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶n̶o̶ ̶c̶a̶t̶c̶h̶ ̶f̶o̶r̶ ̶n̶e̶g̶a̶t̶i̶v̶e̶ ̶v̶a̶l̶u̶e̶s̶.̶

Comment: @Trobbins yeah that sounds about right to me as well

Comment: Either it will call itself recursively with -2, -3 ... until a integer wrap around occurs or will throw an error if D.dequeue() is empty ...

Comment: @Chris this is more of an exercise in unit testing, whereby showing you to make sure D.size() isn't -1 prior to sending its size to the recursive method.

Comment: @Trobbins ah cheers! that clears things up a bit!

Answer (score 2):

The method would run forever (or until it failed due to out-of-memory issues) because the recursive call is n-1 so the end case when n=0 would never be reached.

There could possible be an exception thrown from the class D when the list is empty...

Comment: In the comments @user brings up a good point that it's not necessarily an infinite loop:

_or will throw an error if D.dequeue() is empty_